# Dwolla Offsite Gateway API error

Tags: php, dwolla

I am using Dwolla off-site Gateway API and i am getting an API error as "Total cannot be less than $1". But I pass the correct Total i.e. 131.56 in argument. Then why it give ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, my first gut feeling is that you may have misplaced the "Total" parameter. Checkout this thread for more info:

- [Invalid Total error with Dwolla Server to Server checkout method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522593/invalid-total-error-with-dwolla-server-to-server-checkout-method)